# what are the commands to redirect a subfolder of C:\ProgramData to D:\ProgramData

Tags: windows, command-line, redirection

I am using Garmin Express, a program to update my Garmin Nüvi 2595LTM GPS device. I noticed that Garmin Express is taking up over 6.3GB in the `C:\ProgramData` folder. I only have a small SSD as the `C:` drive, but have 2TB on `D:` and `E:`.

I would like to use `D:` to store programs, and `E:` to do all manner of data storage e.g. backups. I just want to redirect this one program as the others are very small in comparison to this one big offender, Garmin Express.

Can you give me the commands, line by line, I would need to redirect the data location of Garmin Express to `D:` instead of the `C:\ProgramData`?

I would expect it to be something like

```
 mkdir D:\ProgramData
 robocopy /XJ /MIR "C:\ProgramData" "D:\ProgramData"
 mklink /J "C:\ProgramData\Garmin" "D:\ProgramData\Garmin"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to reinstall the app, specifying D as the destination?  There may be other configuration files or registry keys that point to this folder.

Answer (score 0):

If your copying the whole programdata folder you should link it.

```
 mkdir "d:\ProgramData"
 robocopy /XJ /MIR "C:\ProgramData" "D:\ProgramData"
 rename "ProgramData" x
 mklink /j "c:\ProgramData" "d:\ProgramData"
```

Then delete the X folder.